# Remove the redirect chain from website

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

my htaccess rewrite code for redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

i am getting this on my pingdoom test:
Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://panjabi.club/
https://panjabi.club/
```

how can i remove this. 
my WordPress is installed over https, I intend to use only that. this was not before, plus I am using CloudFlare

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do that.

Comment: pingdoom gives my website score D of 68 , should i avoid it ?

Comment: Better to refer to Google Pagespeed Insights responses. Pingdom follows the same code, with varied weights for different tests.

Comment: thanks a lot , i just installed a fresh copy of WordPress, was checking if 100/100 is possible. but this is taking so much of time.